# Sound synthesis: interpolate betweeen frequencies using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm a little lost and hopefully someone can shed some light on this.
Out of curiosity I'm working on a simple softsynth/sequencer. Some ideas
were taken from the .mod format popular in the golden era of home computers.
At the moment it's just a mock-up. Notes are read out from an array holding
up to 64 values, where each position in the array corresponds to a sixteenth
note. So far so good, everything's working as it should and the melody plays
just fine. The problem arises if there's a transition from one note to another.
e.g. f4 -> g#4. Since this is an abrupt change there's a noticeable pop/click
sound. To compensate I'm trying to interpolate between different frequencies
and started to code a simple example to illustrate my idea and verify it's
working.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var sampleRate:int = 44100;
    private var oldFreq:Number = 349.1941058508811;
    private var newFreq:Number = 349.1941058508811;
    private var volume:Number = 15;
    private var position:int = 0;
    private var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
    private var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 100, false, 0x000000);
    private var col:uint = 0xff0000;

    public function Main():void
    {
        if (stage)
            init();
        else
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        bmp.bitmapData = bmpData;
        addChild(bmp);

        for (var a:int = 0; a < 280; a++)
        {
            if (a == 140)
            {
                col = 0x00ff00;
                newFreq = 415.26411519488113;
            }
            if (a == 180)
            {
                col = 0x0000ff;
            }
            oldFreq = oldFreq * 0.9 + newFreq * 0.1;
            bmpData.setPixel(position, Math.sin((position) * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate * oldFreq * 2) * volume + bmpData.height/2, col);
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

[image: interpolated]

The blue dots represent a sine wave at 349.1941058508811 hz, the red 415.26411519488113 hz and the green dots the interpolation.
For my eyes, it looks like this should work!
If I apply this technique to my project however, the result isn't the same!
In fact, if I render the output to a wave file, the transition between those
two frequencies looks like this:

[image: Goldwave screenshot]

Obviously it makes the popping even worse. What could possibly be wrong?
Here's my (shortened )code:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var sampleRate:int = 44100;
    private var bufferSize:int = 8192;
    private var bpm:int = 125;
    private var numberOfRows:int = 64;
    private var currentRow:int = 0;
    private var quarterNoteLength:Number;
    private var sixteenthNoteLength:Number;
    private var numOctaves:int = 8;
    private var patterns:Array = new Array();
    private var currentPattern:int;
    private var songOrder:Array = new Array();
    private var notes:Array = new Array("c-", "c#", "d-", "d#", "e-", "f-", "f#", "g-", "g#", "a-", "a#", "b-");
    private var frequencies:Array = new Array();
    private var samplePosition:Number = 0;
    private var position:int = 0;
    private var channel1:Object = new Object();

    public function Main():void
    {
        if (stage)
            init();
        else
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        quarterNoteLength = sampleRate * 60 / bpm;
        sixteenthNoteLength = quarterNoteLength / 2 / 2;
        for (var a:int = 0; a < numOctaves; a++)
        {
            for (var b:int = 0; b < notes.length; b++)
            {
                frequencies.push(new Array(notes[b % notes.length] + a, 16.35 * Math.pow(2, frequencies.length / 12)));
            }
        }
        patterns.push(new Array("f-4", "", "", "", "g#4", "", "", "f-4", "", "f-4", "a#4", "", "f-4", "", "d#4", "", "f-4", "", "", "", "c-5", "", "", "f-4", "", "f-4", "c#5", "", "c-5", "", "g#4", "", "f-4", "", "c-5", "", "f-5", "", "f-4", "d#4", "", "d#4", "c-4", "", "g-4", "", "f-4", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        songOrder = new Array(0, 0);
        currentRow = 0;
        currentPattern = 0;
        channel1.volume = .05;
        channel1.waveform = "sine";
        channel1.frequency = [0];
        channel1.oldFrequency = [0,0,0,0];
        channel1.noteTriggered = false;

        updateRow();
        var sound:Sound = new Sound();
        sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
        sound.play();
    }

    private function updateRow():void
    {
        var tempNote:String = patterns[songOrder[currentPattern]][currentRow];
        if (tempNote != "")
        {
            channel1.frequency = new Array();
            if (tempNote.indexOf("|") == -1)
            {
                channel1.frequency.push(findFrequency(tempNote));
            }

            channel1.noteTriggered = true;
        }

    }

    private function onSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
    {
        var sampleData:Number;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
        {
            if (++samplePosition == sixteenthNoteLength)
            {
                if (++currentRow == numberOfRows)
                {
                    currentRow = 0;
                    if (++currentPattern == songOrder.length)
                    {
                        currentPattern = 0;
                    }
                }
                updateRow();
                samplePosition = 0;
            }


            for (var a:int = 0; a < (channel1.frequency).length; a++ )
            {
                channel1.oldFrequency[a] = channel1.oldFrequency[a]*0.9+channel1.frequency[a]*0.1;          
            }

            if ((channel1.frequency).length == 1)
            {
                sampleData = generate(channel1.waveform, position, channel1.oldFrequency[0], channel1.volume);
            }
            else
            {
                sampleData = generate(channel1.waveform, position, channel1.oldFrequency[0], channel1.volume);
                sampleData += generate(channel1.waveform, position, channel1.oldFrequency[1], channel1.volume);
            }

            event.data.writeFloat(sampleData);
            event.data.writeFloat(sampleData);

            position++;
        }
    }

    private function generate(waveForm:String, pos:Number, frequency:Number, volume:Number):Number
    {
        var retVal:Number
        switch (waveForm)
        {
            case "square": 
                retVal = Math.sin((pos) * 2 * Math.PI / sampleRate * frequency) > 0 ? volume : -volume;
                break;
            case "sine": 
                retVal = Math.sin((pos) * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate * frequency * 2) * volume;
                break;
            case "sawtooth": 
                retVal = (2 * (pos % (sampleRate / frequency)) / (sampleRate / frequency) - 1) * volume;
                break;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private function findFrequency(inpNote:String):Number
    {
        var retVal:Number;
        for (var a:int = 0; a < frequencies.length; a++)
        {
            if (frequencies[a][0] == inpNote)
            {
                retVal = frequencies[a][1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Thanks! =)

Comment: BTW, your original interpolation also suffers from the issue with different phases, should you replace 140 with 160, and 180 with 210.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss that when you switch frequencies, `pos` value in `generate` loses invariance, that is, `Math.sin((pos) * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate * frequency * 2)` gives VERY different values when ran with different frequencies. Instead, you should use "phase" variable that would run from 0 to 1 then back to 0 and forward again like a sawtooth diagram, and will be forwarded by the value of (current frequency)*(1/sampling rate). So the error is where you add two `generate()` results to one `sampleData` (you plain cannot do that because the interference) and where you use one `position` as a time value to calculate phase instead of accumulated phase. Check this approach, it should work a tad better:

```
private function generate(waveForm:String, var phase:Number, frequency:Number, volume:Number):Number {
    // "pos" changed to "phase". This also means that "generate" should be called once per sample
    var retVal:Number;
    switch (waveForm)
    {
        case "square": 
            retVal = Math.sin(phase * 2 * Math.PI) > 0 ? volume : -volume;
            break;
        case "sine": 
            retVal = Math.sin(phase * 2 * Math.PI ) * volume;
            break;
        case "sawtooth": 
            retVal = (2*Math.abs(2*phase-1)-1)* volume;
            break;
    }
    phase+=frequency/sampleRate;// calculate new phase
    if (phase>1.0) { phase-=1.0; } // normalize phase to 0..1
    return retVal;
}
private function onSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    var sampleData:Number;
    for(var i:int=0;i<bufferSize;i++) {
        if (++samplePosition == sixteenthNoteLength)
        { // leaving this part as is, seems working
            if (++currentRow == numberOfRows)
            {
                currentRow = 0;
                if (++currentPattern == songOrder.length)
                {
                    currentPattern = 0;
                }
            }
            updateRow();
            samplePosition = 0;
        }
        sampleData=0;
        for (i=0;i</*channels.length*/1;i++) {  
            // TODO convert "channel1" to an array 
            // sampleData+=generate(channels[i].waveform, channels[i].phase, channels[i].frequency, channels[i].volume);
            sampleData+=generate(channel1.waveform, channel1.phase, channel1.frequency[0], channel1.volume);
        }
        event.data.writeFloat(sampleData);
        event.data.writeFloat(sampleData);
    }
}
```

In fact, your channels should go to a separate class that will hold all the parameters together (phase, freq, waveform, volume), then, whenever you'd need them to sample, you just could call `channels[i].generateNextSample()` and get a float without all the hassle with parameters. Also, one channel, one frequency, so skip those "oldFrequency" stuff.

As a follow-up, a sketch for `Channel` class:

```
public class Channel {
    public const WAVE_SINE:int=0;
    public const WAVE_SQUARE:int=1;
    public const WAVE_SAWTOOTH:int=2;
    private var phase:Number=0;
    private var currentVolume:Number=0;
    public var volume:Number; // 0 to 1, should build a setter to normalize
    public var frequency:Number=0;
    public var waveform:int; // should also not allow changing this mid-play probably
    public function Channel(v:Number=0,wf:int=WAVE_SINE,f:Number=0) {
        this.volume=v;
        this.frequency=f;
        this.waveform=wf;
        phase=0;
        currentVolume=0;
    }
    public function generateNextSample():Number {...} // use the generate() code above to fill
    public function reset():void { currentVolume=0; phase=0; } // POW
    // rest to taste, enabled, active, whatever
}
```

An example of use:

```
var ch:Vector.<Channel>=new Vector.<Channel>();
ch.push(new Channel());
function onSampleData(e:SampleDataEvent):void {
    for (var j:int=0;j<8192;j++) {
        // here to input code that can alter channels' freqs, volumes etc
        var sd:Number=0;
        for (var i:int=ch.length-1; i>=0;i--) { sd+=ch[i].generateNextSample(); }
        e.data.writeFloat(sd);
        e.data.writeFloat(sd);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it might have to do with the phase but couldn't
figure out how to solve it.
Anyway, If I keep the phase in bettween different frequencies, the transition
looks a little like this:
[Goldwave 1](https://i.imgsafe.org/d2406dd7d1.jpg)
and if I reset it to 0 as soon as a new note is triggered, it's like
this:
[Goldwave 2](https://i.imgsafe.org/d242609d70.jpg)

I can compensate by interpolating between the different amplitudes at the start of a new note but maybe there's a better way. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks for your helpful answer Vesper!

Comment: You can interpolate the volume from current to changed, this will eliminate the bump in "Goldwave 1", just make it so that interpolation goes over several dozens of samples. This needs a setter on `volume` and a code to slowly adjust `currentVolume` to the volume specified in `generateNextSample()`.